# Can not set enabled hours with Zebra Datepicker

Tags: jquery, zebra-ui-framework

I have just downloaded and installed this script and everything seems to work alright except for the option `enabled_hours`.

I want to configure the script to enable only a set of available hours like this:

```
enabled_hours: ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']
```

but on the picker only 11 is shown and if I try to change it with the arrows then UNDEFINED appears. Enabled minutes wont work either

```
enabled_minutes: ['00']
```

is this a bug or im doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug when enabled hours were specified as strings instead of integers. The bug is now fixed. See [this](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/issues/148) for more information.